# Get the name of controls (buttons) dynamically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I have 10 buttons namely `button01`, `button02` ... `button10`. What I want is how to manipulate it.

```
For x=1 to 10
  button(x).text = "blah" 'from database...or something
next
```

I need to do this because I have 10 buttons or more and I want to manipulate it through initialization. So that I don't do it manually one by one. I don't know how to do this. I'm still new in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not need to do it in this error-prone way just to save you some lines of code. But if you really want....

You can use a `Panel` or another container control that groups the related controls logically. Then use `MyPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()` to filter and find all the buttons there.

```
For Each btn As Button In MyPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
    btn.Text = "blah" 'from database...or something
Next
```

Another way is to put them all in an array or other collection type like `List(Of Button)` first and loop over them afterwards:

```
Dim myButtons = {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6}
For Each btn In myButtons
    btn.Text = "blah" 'from database...or something
Next
```

Last you could use [`ControlCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) to find controls with a given string for its name:

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Dim btns = Me.Controls.Find("button" & i, True)
    If btns.Length > 0 Then
        btns(0).Text = "blah" 'from database...or something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: this is very good, i used your last option. probably what i needed. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through the parent container of these buttons.

Say you are holding these controls inside a panel called `PnlTest`, then you have to do it like this:

```
For Each xControls As Control In PnlTest.Controls

    If TypeOf xControls Is Button Then
        xControls.Text = "blah" 'from database...or something
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Me.Controls("button" & i.ToString("00")).Text = "blah"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the method [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) as such from the WebControl:

```
For x=1 to 10
    FindControl("button" & if(x < 10, "0" & x, x) = "blah" 'from database...or something
next
```

**EDIT:** I primarily use C#, not VB, so it may need some alteration. However, the approach is the same I would believe.

Comment: I assume OP is asking for Winforms, there is no `FindControl` in winforms.

Answer (score -2):

zeroyevi cubosoft.cl -- DevExpress  -- la clave esta (bar.button.item) en Me.RibbonControl.Items("NAME_BUTTON" ).Enabled = True or false

```
Private Sub GetSearchPerfilModulosBotones(ByVal _id_perfil As String)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim _act_btns As Boolean

    Dim _name_btns As String
    Dim _name_module As String = Me.Name.ToString()
    Try

        Dim _ControlDatosSistema As New ControlDatosSistema()
        With _ControlDatosSistema
            dt = .GetSearchPerfilModulosBotones(_id_perfil, _name_module )'SQL QUERY


          If (dt.Rows.Count >= 1) Then
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

                    _act_btns = row("ACT_BTNS") 'BOTONES PERFIL True or False
                    _name_btns = row("NAME_BTNS").ToString()'NOMBRE BOTONES TABLA
                    Me.RibbonControl.Items(_name_btns ).Enabled = _act_btns 
                Next
            End If



        End With
        _ControlDatosSistema = Nothing
        dt.Dispose()



    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include an explanation on this.

Comment: I do not know what part of the code was not understood since to run the information from database and get the names and values ​​of on or off is also a special component  DevExpress