# Unable to find a control on my page by name

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have seen multiple examples of code where someone has referred to a control by name, similar to the following:

```
Dim NameBox As TextBox = Me.Controls("ID of control")
```

I am attempting do to the same, but running into an error. My page includes several of these:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDaEName1" Width="300px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDaEName2" Width="300px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDaEName3" Width="300px" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Do While SQLdr.Read()
    NameBox = Me.Controls("txtDaEName" & iCounter.ToString)
    NameBox.Text = SQLdr("NameOfItem")
    iCounter += 1
LOOP
```

However, I am getting an error. When I go to assign NameBox to `Me.Controls("txtDaEName" & iCounter)`, I get back the error:

```
"Conversion from string ""txtDaEName1"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."
```

I have seen some places where it says that Me.Controls() requires an integer value in parenthesis, and the error seems to support this...but I also see code samples posted elsewhere where they're using Me.Controls("TheIDName") and it seems to work.

`TryCast(Me.FindControl("txtDaEName" & iCounter.ToString), Textbox)` isn't finding it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The control needs to be created before you try and find it. If you search for it in say a button event and only create it in pre render, the control doesn't exist yet, even after a postback. Are the controls generated dynamically?
Also since FindControl doesn't find it, Me.Controls doesn't contain it either at the time. You can try and debug it by printing out all IDs in Me.Controls.

Comment: You can print out debug information with Response.Write(string). We use a textbox object on the page for dumping all kinds of debug information into only visible to development staff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the name of controls (buttons) dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266954/get-the-name-of-controls-buttons-dynamically)